# How to combine an admin module from different ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, openstreetmap, django-guardian

Because I need to display the map for a location field I was using `gisadmin.OSMGeoAdmin` but now I installed django-guardian to have object-level permissions.. now my module has to be with `GuardedModelAdmin` losing the map field to a simple textarea.

Is it possible to maintain all the `GuardedModelAdmin` functionality and bring the location map field like the `OSMGeoAdmin` in the same module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the constructs of the objects, but you could try (might cause clashes):

```
class MyGuardedOSMGeoAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin, OSMGeoAdmin):  # or visa versa
    pass


class MyAdmin(MyGuardedOSMGeoAdmin):
    # your declarations


admin.site.register(MyModel, MyAdmin)
```

Detailed information on (multiple) inheritance can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance)